# UIViewController interface orientation is wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

In the `UIViewController` rotation method(s) I have a problem when performing the device rotation

inside of the method

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

I am getting incorrect values

According to the documentation:

> Sent to the view controller just before the user interface begins
>   rotating. Subclasses may override this method to perform additional
>   actions immediately prior to the rotation. For example, you might use
>   this method to disable view interactions, stop media playback, or
>   temporarily turn off expensive drawing or live updates. You might also
>   use it to swap the current view for one that reflects the new
>   interface orientation. ***When this method is called, the
>   interfaceOrientation property still contains the view’s original
>   orientation.*** Your implementation of this method must call super at
>   some point during its execution. This method is called regardless of
>   whether your code performs one-step or two-step rotations.

I am holding the device strait up (right after launching the app the device is physically in portrait mode) - all the views are correctly aligned for portrait mode

But in the method I am getting wrong values:

```
    -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
    // getting the wrong interface orientation here!!!!
   // just checking the current orientation for debug
        UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
   // the first time the device is rotated getting this value for current orientation:
        // currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
    }
```

even worst than this strange case of wrong orientation is in this same method for 'will rotate to interface orientation' the current interface orientation and the destination interface orientation are identical i.e:

```
self.interfaceOrientation === toInterfaceOrientation
```

So whats the point of this method being called by the framework???

This results in all my UIView placement code not being calculating correctly on initial rotation of the device.

Why is this flag not set correctly?!?!

P.S

After rotating the device for the second time - the flags are set correctly and the views "align" themselves properly.

Answer (score 0):

u will get correct value, suppose u are holding the device in port rite , then u turn it t landscape mode, then this method is called

//called first

```
 -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
  {
      //check which orientation hear   
      if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
       {
             NSLog(@"turning t landscape");
       }
      else
       {
             NSLog(@"turning t portrite");
       }
  }
```

method called hear `toInterfaceOrientation` contains (for our example) UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`or`UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`, this indicates that device will going to turn to landscape left or rite

after this, below methods called in order

```
 - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews  

 - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

 - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

get called, hear in last method `fromInterfaceOrientation` contains (for our example) old value or previous orientation flag, that is `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` or `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`

u want t know the current orientation then u can use

```
 UIInterfaceOrientation  orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
  if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
  {
    NSLog(@"landscape");
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"portrite");
  }
```

for more information about this u can see this [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)

Comment: Thats not correct at all . The current interface orientation should not have been changed at this stage and definitly should not equal the 'toInterfaceOrientation' ever (WITH A CAPITAL EVERRRRR) in any orientation change methods. That makes absolutely no sense

Comment: it is the way orientation methods are called see the document that i linked it has pretty good explanation...